# How to use context providers in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm wondering what the best approach would be for using using context providers in stories. At the moment, I'm passing the context's value across in `args` and then in a `decorator` passing that context to the provider, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Let me know what y'all reckon. This is what I've got:

A context provider:

```js
export const SomeContext = React.createContext(false);

export const SomeContextProvider = ({ someContext, children }) => {
  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider value={someContext}>{children}</SomeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

A context consumer:

```js
export function ContextConsumer({ props }) {
  const someContext = useContext(SomeContext);

  return (
    <div>
      I'm a context consumer and someContext is {someContext ? "true" : "false"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

A decorator:

```js
(Story, context) => {
    return (
      <SomeContextProvider someContext={context.args.someContext}>
        <Story />
      </SomeContextProvider>
    );
  }
```

A story:

```js
const Template = (args) => <ContextConsumer {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  someContext: true
};
```